Accessing appointments in todo agenda
When I attempt to review an appointment the screen blinks but the appointment can't be seen and an error message only shows error and the outlook symbol.

There is hardly any information here which can be used to debug your problem. Please provide details: the entry in your appointment file, what exactly you are doing to produce the agenda, what the error is, the exact error message, what that mysterious "outlook symbol" is, maybe version information and anything else you can think of that might be helpful in diagnosing the problem.
